# Distribute Crystal Reports files

Tags: crystal-reports

Can I distribute Crystal Reports (CR2016) report files where clients are able to refresh live data but unable to access the Designs?

I have checked with the CR2016 features, it's not possible to do so.

I will need 3rd party program which is able to encrypt the files so I don't have to distribute the .RPT itself.

Just wonder if this tool exists.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Export the rpt to rptr (read-only) format.

Any 3rd-party viewer that uses a recent version of the Crystal runtime can then run that report and refresh data. See list of 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewers [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers).

Comment: But with rptr format, the client cannot refresh the report, while rpt format, the client has full access of the report.

I have checked the list, seems all 3rd-party viewers use rpt format.
I did see LogicityPro has encrypt feature, but not sure how it works, still checking with them.

Comment: I just tested that scenario with my viewer software and refreshing data using an .rptr report works fine.  
Where did you see information to the contrary?

Comment: Just to clarify, certain extra functionality such as translating the report to a different language, or redirecting the report to use a different data source than it was designed for is indeed disabled. That is because RPTR doesn't allow changes to the design of the report. 
But normal functionality such as refreshing data is clearly supported.